# What is possible for Hashset<> default value?

Tags: java, android, hashset

```
public class HeaderSharedPreferences {

    private final String PREF_NAME = "com.example.keepair.myapplication.pref";

    public final static String PREF_COOKIE = "PREF_COOKIE";    

    static Context mContext;

    public HeaderSharedPreferences(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void put(String key, HashSet<String> value) {
        SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,
                Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        editor.putString(key, THIS_PLACE); // I want to know right value and value type of THIS_PLACE
        editor.commit();
    }
```

This is for SharedPreferences, If i have to use Hashset, what is good for 'THIS_PLACE'? 
I want to store Token key.

Comment: Is it just my restricted knowledge about Android; or does this question really make no sense at all? I have no idea what this code is supposed to do; and what are looking to hear from us.

Comment: sorry, when i first learnd that code, that code is  `public void put(String key, String value) {
  SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,
    Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

  editor.putString(key, value);
  editor.commit();
 }`
but i just want to change `String` to `Hashset` type.
It was going well when `String` was given, but case of `Hashset` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [`putStringSet(String key, Set<String> values)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) is more appropriate in your case.

**Your code will then be:**

```
editor.putStringSet(key, value);
```

Otherwise with `putString(String key, String value)` only one value will be taken into account

Comment: Is it all method i can use for Sharedpreference.Editor?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: You helped me. Thank you.